# Join multi create in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, sql-insert, join

I would like to insert new records in 3 Tables at once. Is there any solution to use one create or join three tables?

In SingleController.php:

```
$single = Single::create([
                    'structure_id' => $request->structure_id,
                    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                ]);

$structure = Structure::create([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                ]);

$placement = Placement::create([
                    'structure_id' => $request->structure_id,
                    'seed' => $request->seed,
                ]);
```

In model of Structure.php :

```
public function singles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Single::class);
}

public function placements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Placement::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating `Structure` you could do like this:

```
$structure->singles()->create({
    'structure_id' => $request->structure_id,
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
})

$structure->placements()->create({
    'structure_id' => $request->structure_id,
    'seed' => $request->seed,
})
```

Follow the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)